# stdarg and NULL arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want a function that, when called with a varying number of arguments, return the first non-NULL one. I've tried this, but it core dumps on `for` loop:

```
char *first(char *args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char *r = NULL, *p;

    va_start(ap, args);
    for (p = args; *p; p++) {
        r = va_arg(ap, char*);
        if (r != NULL) break;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return r;
}

char *q = NULL;
char *w = NULL;
char *e = "zzz";
char *r = NULL;
printf("%s\n", first(q, w, e, r)); // ought to print "zzz"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`args` is not an array of arguments. It's just the first argument you passed to `first`. So its value in this case is the value of `q`.

You can't *iterate* over va args like you are doing.

Do this:

```
va_start(ap, args);
do {
    r = va_arg(ap, char*);
    if (r != NULL) break;
} while (1);
va_end(ap);
```

This will crash if you have no non-NULL argument, though, so you would better pass the number of arguments as first argument:

```
char *first(int nargs, ...)
{
    char *r = NULL;

    va_start(ap, nargs);
    for( ; nargs; nargs--) {
        r = va_arg(ap, char*);
        if (r != NULL) break;
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return r;
}

first(4, q, w, e, r);
```

Alternatively, use a sentinel:

```
char *first(char *first, ...)
{
    char *r = first;

    va_start(ap, first);
    while (!r) {
        r = va_arg(ap, char*);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return r == &sentinel ? NULL : r;
}

char sentinel; // its address is unique among other pointers

first(q, w, e, r, &sentinel);
```

Comment: The function with nargs doesn't work it the first argument is non-NULL: first(4, e, q, w, r). The one with sentinel works fine. Thanks.